# ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar() doesn't work when called directly inside a widget build function

Tags: flutter, dart, toast, snackbar

While looking for examples for using flutter `SnackBar` with `ScaffoldMessenger`, I only found usages with `onPressed` function:

```
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
            child: ElevatedButton(
              child: ...,
              onPressed: () => _showToast(context),
            ));
      }
    
      void _showToast(BuildContext context) {
        final scaffold = ScaffoldMessenger.of(context);
        scaffold.showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(content: const Text('Added to favorite')),
        );
      }
    }
```

but non of the examples explain why one have to use it with onPressed only,
so I tried it my self and used in directly inside the build function:

```
         Widget build(BuildContext context) {
           _showToast(context);   <---
           return Container(
              child: ElevatedButton(
                ...,
            ));
      }
```

but than I got this error:

[image]

and I am not sure why this it happening.

I ended up giving Scaffold a key and using the `GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>` approach, but I really want to understand why using `ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar()` without a callback\onPressed didn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

while `ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)` we need to give some time to be rendered properly(for full Scaffold). we can know the time from `addPostFrameCallback`. Also if you try to show the middle of widgets, the 1st portion will render but rest widgets will face this issue.

here is the soulution on `build` method.

```
  WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      _showToast(context);
    });
```

to understand the concept properly we can do something like this.

```
Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        height: 100,
        color: Colors.cyanAccent,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text("This text will render "),
            Builder(builder: (context) {
              _showToast(context);

              ///but you will be able to see Message
              return Text("it will cause error");
            }),
            Text("This text will not render "),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: I accepted this answer as it explains the full scaffold rendering notion and gives an example for this concept.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add or declare your snackbar inside **Future.deleayd**

```
Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () async {
                  yourSnackBarFunction();
                });
```

Comment: My goal is to understand the reason I get the error. though I assume your solution will work...

Comment: I don't recommend it, it is somehow 'cheating' the framework and generally not advisable.

Comment: I kind of solved the issue with GlobalKey (as I mentioned in the post) but I really want to understand why it is happening

Comment: Think of "build" method as a recipe to Flutter engine how to assemble your widget if anything happens which results in a need for rebuild. See https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ScaffoldState/build.html.

Comment: @vigdora I think future.deleyed that runs its computation after a delay.

The [computation] will be executed after the given [duration] has passed, and the future is completed with the result of the computation.

Answer (score 1):

In Flutter **build** function is called by the framework itself whenever a widget needs to be rebuilt. It can occur many times!

On the other hand, you usually want to display a toast / snackbar when you want to **inform your user about something**. So you can display a snackbar from **onPressed** and many other places, but the build function itself is only for building a widget, and not responding directly to user actions.

Comment: Thanks, but when flutter binds you to use context with scaffoldMessenger, it restricts you to use it only with the build method in stateless widgets...
and I might want to use toast outside of the build function..

Comment: I might be wrong but I think you can access context from other places as well, not only the build method. For example if you declare a method within "class _SomeState extends State<Some>" you have context in the method. Give it a try and sorry if I am misleading, but I remember using like that.

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/context.html

Comment: Check the above link, it seems to me that there is a getter named 'context' which you can access from State objects. It is a little confusing that build functions receive this as a function parameter with the same name.

Comment: I will check the above, but I think your idea is related to stateful widgets, and my question is more on stateless, I am starting to feel like the key approach (GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>) is the right one as it will allow me more flexibility